# Rails where statement with datetime.month

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find the data points within a database (PG) whose date is within a certain month (and would also quite like to check the year is the same also)

I have tried:

`my_data.where("date.month = ?", month )`

where 'month' is an integer (eg from Time.new.month) but doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the query will be like this:

```
my_data.where("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = ?", month)
```